# How to calculate the average value of all items stored in a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a couple of procedures that return a `SYS_REFCURSOR`. One is called `cust_cursor` and the other is `prod_cursor`. The latter stores products' IDs and quantities. So far, I am able to print each individual quantity, as shown in the following anonymous block.

```
DECLARE
    cust_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    cust_id       ex1.address_detail.id_customer%TYPE;
    addr_id       ex1.address_detail.id_address%TYPE;
    prod_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    prod_id       ex1.SALES_ORDER_DETAIL.ID_PROD%TYPE;
    prod_qty      ex1.SALES_ORDER_DETAIL.ORDER_QTY%TYPE;
BEGIN
    ex1.INFO_SALES.TOP_CUSTOMERS (cust_cursor);

    LOOP
        FETCH cust_cursor INTO cust_id, addr_id;

        EXIT WHEN cust_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        ex1.info_sales.top_products (addr_id, prod_cursor);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            'Customer' || CHR (9) || '|' || CHR (9) || 'Address');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            cust_id || CHR (9) || CHR (9) || '|' || CHR (9) || addr_id);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            'Product' || CHR (9) || '|' || CHR (9) || 'Quantity');

        LOOP
            FETCH prod_cursor INTO prod_id, prod_qty;

            EXIT WHEN prod_cursor%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                prod_id || CHR (9) || CHR (9) || '|' || CHR (9) || prod_qty);
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE prod_cursor;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            '------------------------------------------------------------');
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cust_cursor;
END;
```

How can I calculate the average value of these quantities per customer in `prod_cursor`?

I am providing an example query to get `prod_cursor`.

```
SELECT products.ID_PROD, products.ORDER_QTY
  FROM (SELECT sale.id_sales_order,
               sale.customer_id,
               sale.bill_address_id,
               detail.id_prod,
               detail.unit_price,
               detail.order_qty,
               detail.unit_price * detail.order_qty AS "Total Sales",
               ROW_NUMBER ()
                   OVER (ORDER BY detail.unit_price * detail.order_qty DESC)
                   AS product_rank
          FROM ex1.sales  sale
               INNER JOIN ex1gon.sales_order_detail detail
                   ON sale.ID_SALES_ORDER = detail.ID_SALES_ORDER
         WHERE sale.BILL_ADDRESS_ID = 100) products
 WHERE products.PRODUCT_RANK < 5;
```

Comment: Can you change procedure which returns you the `prod_cursor` ?

Comment: @Seyran Yes, yes I can.

Comment: Sorry, do I understand your question correct? You want to calculate avg of all quantities, or quantities by customer returned in  'prod_cursor '

Comment: @Seyran: average quantity per customer returned in `prod_cursor`.

Comment: Ok, then add `avg(prod_qty)` to the cursor query. Can you provide `prod_cursor` query ?

Comment: @Seyran: OK, I'm going to provide the `prod_cursor` query in the original post. The problem I am having with adding avg(prod_qty) is that I it is "not a single group by function".

Comment: @Seyran, in fact, I think that I must get the average in another procedure, because, its result will be a single row, whereas `prod_cursor` stores several rows.

Comment: A cursor does not store anything. It's just a specification for how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your comment about single row result of average, the value will be same for all rows in cursor, it depends how you will use it in fetch.

You can do it with analityc function

```
SELECT products.ID_PROD, products.ORDER_QTY, 
 avg(products.ORDER_QTY) over (partition by products.customer_id) AvgQnty
  FROM (SELECT sale.id_sales_order,
               sale.customer_id,
               sale.bill_address_id,
               detail.id_prod,
               detail.unit_price,
               detail.order_qty,
               detail.unit_price * detail.order_qty AS "Total Sales",
               ROW_NUMBER ()
                   OVER (ORDER BY detail.unit_price * detail.order_qty DESC)
                   AS product_rank
          FROM ex1.sales  sale
               INNER JOIN ex1gon.sales_order_detail detail
                   ON sale.ID_SALES_ORDER = detail.ID_SALES_ORDER
         WHERE sale.BILL_ADDRESS_ID = 100) products
 WHERE products.PRODUCT_RANK < 5;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had not thought about using the `OVER` function. It works perfectly for what I need.

Comment: Welcome, if you have time read about analityc functions, they are very useful in report style queries, where some row independent calculations should be done.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the advice. I will make sure to read about them.